# CTE can't be referenced from query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm relatively new to SQL (here it is PostgreSQL) and stuck at a query I've been working on. I created a MWE for it: I get a syntax error at `new_years`, but I don't see any reason for it:

```
WITH new_years AS
( 
    SELECT mov_year FROM movie WHERE mov_year > 2000
)
SELECT m.mov_title, m.mov_year
FROM movie m, new_years
WHERE m.mov_year IN new_years;
```

Then I tried reformatting my query, and also do not understand why the reformatting doesn't work, as `new_years` can't be found! Why is it that the alias m for movie can be referenced in `WHERE`, but the alias new_years cannot? Are some aliases different from others?

```
SELECT m.mov_title, m.mov_year
FROM movie m, (SELECT mov_year FROM movie WHERE mov_year > 2000) AS new_years
WHERE m.mov_year IN new_years;
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` needs to refer to a list of values, not a CTE.

This would be syntactically correct...

```
WHERE m.mov_year IN (SELECT mov_year FROM new_years);
```

It would also seem to give gibberish results.

Perhaps you mean...

```
WITH new_years AS
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT mov_year FROM movie WHERE mov_year > 2000
)
SELECT
  m.mov_title, m.mov_year
FROM
  movie m
INNER JOIN
  new_years
    ON new_years.mov_year = m.mov_year
```

Or...

```
WITH new_years AS
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT mov_year FROM movie WHERE mov_year > 2000
)
SELECT
  m.mov_title, m.mov_year
FROM
  movie m
WHERE
  m.mov_year IN (SELECT mov_year FROM new_years);
```

But then, why not just do this?

```
SELECT
  m.mov_title, m.mov_year
FROM
  movie m
WHERE
  m.mov_year > 2000
```

Comment: Remove the inefficient `DISTINCT` and I will upvote.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - Without the `DISTINCT` the resulting list would include unnecessary duplicates.  I maintain it to be correct, especially for the `INNER JOIN` version.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's right, the last query you wrote is the simplest, I was just toying around to make a MWE with the same problem. So IN cannot be used with a CTE, and it seems IN doesn't work with CREATE VIEW either. I didn't know that, thank you ^^

Comment: @doublefelix - Please upvote and/or accept any answers that help you.

Comment: I'd say that sorting the list is more expensive than searching through the duplicates, but I didn't benchmark it.

Comment: As for the second variation in my question, how can I understand that `m` can be referenced in WHERE, but `new_years` cannot? Is it the case that derived tables cannot be referenced in WHERE?

Comment: @doublefelix - In the second example `new_years` ***is*** referenced in the `WHERE`.  It's just that `IN <cte>` or `IN <table>` or `IN <view>` are all syntax errors.  In all cases you need `IN (SELECT x FROM y)` where `y` can be a CTE, a table or a view.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - In the `INNER JOIN` version, not having a `DISTINCT` would cause every movie to be duplicated by the number of movies made that year.

Comment: Oh wow, that really clears things up. So IN can only be used with explicit subqueries? Odd but very good to know.